# flutter web auth0 universal login - Does not provide credentials on redirection

Tags: flutter, dart, auth0, flutter-go-router

Happy New Year.  I'm building a web app using flutter and VS code, and want to implement auth0's universal login. I have modelled my code on auth0's sample code but the architecture and project structure are my own. I am using *go_router* for navigation.

Originally I was using Bloc in my project, and I was attempting to redirect to a separate page (other than my login page) upon successful authentication, but this led me into all sorts of difficulties; so I have now stripped my project back to one login page, and the idea is that when auth0 redirects back to this page after a successful authentication, the auth0 sdk is queried for a successful login, and then (presuming a successful authentication) redirects to another internal page.

I am debugging in VS Code and using Chrome (latest versions, running on MacOS). From my login page, I am able to redirect to the Auth0 login page, and can authenticate OK. However on redirection back to my app, the application code (and in particular the properties of the Auth0Web object) do not reflect the successful authentication.

When I review the request and response in Chrome's Developer tools tab, everything looks OK to my untrained eyes. Under the NETWORK tab there is a TOKEN entry, with a Response which looks like this (my redactions with ellipsis):

> {
> "access_token": "eyJ...Chrg",
> "id_token": "eyJ.....BZxA",
> "scope": "openid profile email",
> "expires_in": 86400,
> "token_type": "Bearer" }

Additionally, under PAYLOAD, the redirect header looks as expected:

> redirect_uri: http://localhost:49713/#/login

My app initialization code is as follows (including instantiation of an Auth0Web object):

```
void main() async {
  await dotenv.load(fileName: "dotenv");
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final Auth0Web auth0 =
        Auth0Web(dotenv.env['AUTH0_DOMAIN']!, dotenv.env['AUTH0_CLIENT_ID']!);
    final String auth0Audience = dotenv.env['AUTH0_AUDIENCE'].toString();
    UserProfile? auth0AuthenticatedUser;

    auth0.onLoad(audience: auth0Audience).then((final credentials) => () {
          auth0AuthenticatedUser = credentials?.user;
        });

    MaterialApp materialApp = MaterialApp.router(
      routerConfig: appRouter(auth0),
      title: 'Assessments',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
    );

    return materialApp;
  }
}
```

This is the code for my go_router declaration:

```
// GoRouter configuration
GoRouter appRouter(Auth0Web auth0) {
  return GoRouter(
    routes: [
      GoRoute(
        path: '/login',
        builder: (context, state) => LoginPage2(auth0: auth0),
      ),
      GoRoute(
        path: '/coreMenu',
        builder: (context, state) => const CoreMenuPage(),
      ),
      GoRoute(
          path: '/',
          builder: (context, state) => const DefaultPage(),
          redirect: (context, state) => '/login')
    ],
  );
}
```

And here is the Dart code for the login page, from where I both redirect to auth0, and to which auth0 should redirect after successful authentication:

```
class LoginPage2 extends StatefulWidget {
  final Auth0Web auth0;

  const LoginPage2({super.key, required this.auth0});

  @override
  State<LoginPage2> createState() => LoginPage2State();
}

class LoginPage2State extends State<LoginPage2> {
  bool loggedInState = false;
  String redirectUrl = dotenv.env['AUTH0_LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL'].toString();
  String appBarName = dotenv.env['APP_BAR_NAME'].toString();

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    loginHasValidCredentials().then((hasValidCredentials) {
      loggedInState = hasValidCredentials;
    });
  }

  Future<bool> loginHasValidCredentials() async {
    final loggedIn = await widget.auth0.hasValidCredentials();
    if (loggedIn) {
      await widget.auth0.credentials();
    }
    return loggedIn;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (loggedInState) {
      context.go('/coreMenu');
      return const SizedBox.shrink();
    } else {
      return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text(appBarName),
            backgroundColor: Colors.purple,
            foregroundColor: Colors.white,
          ),
          body: Column(children: [
            // Logo
            const Icon(Icons.quiz),

            // Login button, or Go to button (Contained button)
            ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () =>
                    {widget.auth0.loginWithRedirect(redirectUrl: redirectUrl)},
                child: const Text('LOGIN')),

            // Sign up button, or Log out button (Text button)
            TextButton(
                onPressed: () => throw Exception(), //todo
                child: const Text('SIGN UP / CREATE ACCOUNT'))
          ]));
    }
  }
}
```

**What I am expecting to happen** is that when authentication is completed successfully, and auth0 redirects my browser to `/login`, then the following code will run, causing a redirect to `/coreMenu` as a result:

```
   if (loggedInState) {
      context.go('/coreMenu');
```

What is actually happening is that when the redirect happens, `loggedInState` is always `false`.

I have run out of ideas for further troubleshooting and would be grateful for any tips or advice as to where I am going wrong with this.

Many TIA.

**UPDATE**

I modified my code to use a FutureBuilder, and now I am seeing this exception, which seems to surface only in Chrome's Developer Tools console, rather than 'bubbling up' into VS Code:

> error :  web_exception.WebException.new Symbol(Auth0Exception.code) :
> "missing_transaction" Symbol(Auth0Exception.details) :
> IdentityMap.new {Symbol(IdentityMap._map): Map(0),
> Symbol(IdentityMap._modifications): 0} Symbol(Auth0Exception.message)
> :  "Invalid state" Symbol(*jsError) :  Error: missing_transaction:
> Invalid state at Object.throw* [as throw]
> (http://localhost:49713/dart_sdk.js:5679:11) at
> auth0_flutter_plugin_real.Auth0FlutterPlugin.new.initialize
> (http://localhost:49713/packages/auth0_flutter/src/web/auth0_flutter_plugin_real.dart.lib.js:74:25)
> at initialize.throw () at
> http://localhost:49713/dart_sdk.js:40303:38 at _RootZone.runBinary
> (http://localhost:49713/dart_sdk.js:40173:59) at
> _FutureListener.thenAwait.handleError (http://localhost:49713/dart_sdk.js:35574:33) at handleError
> (http://localhost:49713/dart_sdk.js:36167:51) at
> _Future._propagateToListeners (http://localhost:49713/dart_sdk.js:36193:17) at [_completeError]
> (http://localhost:49713/dart_sdk.js:36036:23) at
> async._AsyncCallbackEntry.new.callback
> (http://localhost:49713/dart_sdk.js:36079:31) at Object._microtaskLoop
> (http://localhost:49713/dart_sdk.js:40602:13) at _startMicrotaskLoop
> (http://localhost:49713/dart_sdk.js:40608:13) at
> http://localhost:49713/dart_sdk.js:36410:9 code :  (...) details :
> IdentityMap.new hashCode :  1032338342 message :  "Invalid state"
> runtimeType :  dart._Type.new Symbol(dartx.hashCode) :  1032338342
> Symbol(dartx.runtimeType) :  dart._Type.new [[Prototype]] :
> Auth0Exception